# Failed to find mapping description. Please configure JdbcType to associate cache 'PersonCache' with JdbcPojoStore ERROR

Tags: java, mysql, caching, gridgain, ignite

I used apache ignite's import-schema tool to create a mysql database(database is PERSON and the table is called person, it is similar to the one given in the H2 example) and it generates the java files (CacheConfig.java, PersonKey.java, Person.java) and ignite-type-metadata.xml file. I wrote a similar program (as given in the Automatic Persistence topic - Demo.java) which is given below. But when I run this, I get the error:

```
Failed to execute job [jobId=37be440c351-3d8e0b33-f744-4765-8c96-962dbe0248ad, ses=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob, dep=GridDeployment [ts=1459219659857, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@23137792, clsLdrId=27be440c351-3d8e0b33-f744-4765-8c96-962dbe0248ad, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=2], taskClsName=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob, sesId=17be440c351-3d8e0b33-f744-4765-8c96-962dbe0248ad, startTime=1459219659857, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=3d8e0b33-f744-4765-8c96-962dbe0248ad, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@23137792, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, subjId=3d8e0b33-f744-4765-8c96-962dbe0248ad, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null, startTime=1459219659938, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false, lsnr=null, state=INIT]]], jobId=37be440c351-3d8e0b33-f744-4765-8c96-962dbe0248ad]]
    class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find mapping description [cache=PersonCache, typeId=class apache.ignite.schemas.PersonKey]. Please configure JdbcType to associate cache 'PersonCache' with JdbcPojoStore.
```

How to fix it?

This is the DemoDemo.java to run the example:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.cache.Cache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteException;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStore;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.dialect.MySQLDialect;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.transactions.Transaction;
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool;

/**
 * This demo demonstrates the use of cache with {@link CacheJdbcPojoStore}
 * together with automatic Ignite schema-import utility.
 * <p>
 * This Demo can work stand-alone. You can also choose to start
 * several {@link DemoNode} instances as well to form a cluster.
 */
public class DemoDemo {


       static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/PERSON";
       static final String USER = "root";
       static final String PASS = "mysql";
    /**
     * Constructs and returns a fully configured instance of a {@link CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory}.
     */
    private static class MySQLDemoStoreFactory<K, V> extends CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<K, V> {
        // {@inheritDoc} 
        @Override public CacheJdbcPojoStore<K, V> create() {
            setDialect(new MySQLDialect());

            setDataSource(JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:mysql://localhost/PERSON", "root", "mysql"));

            return super.create();
        }
    }



    /**
     * Executes demo.
     *
     * @param args Command line arguments, none required.
     * @throws IgniteException If example execution failed.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException {
        System.out.println(">>> Start demo...");

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

           //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
           try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


           //STEP 3: Open a connection
           System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
                 //STEP 4: Execute a query
                  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                  stmt = conn.createStatement();
                  String sql;
                  sql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM PERSON";
                  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                  //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
                  while(rs.next()){
                     //Retrieve by column name
                     int id  = rs.getInt("id");
                     String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
                     String lastName = rs.getString("last_name");

                     //Display values
                     System.out.print("ID: " + id);

                     System.out.print(", First: " + firstName);
                     System.out.println(", Last: " + lastName);
                  } 

           }catch(SQLException se){
                  //Handle errors for JDBC
                  se.printStackTrace();
               }catch(Exception e){
                  //Handle errors for Class.forName
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }finally{
                  //finally block used to close resources
                  try{
                     if(stmt!=null)
                        stmt.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se2){
                  }// nothing we can do
                  try{
                     if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se){
                     se.printStackTrace();
                  }
               }

        // Start Ignite node.
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
            // Configure cache store.
            CacheConfiguration<PersonKey, Person> cfg =
                CacheConfig.cache("PersonCache", new MySQLDemoStoreFactory<PersonKey, Person>());

            try (IgniteCache<PersonKey, Person> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg)) {
                // Preload cache from database.
                preload(cache);

                // Read-through from database
                // and store in cache.
                readThrough(cache);

                // Perform transaction and
                // write-through to database.
                transaction(ignite, cache);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Demonstrates cache preload from database.
     */
    private static void preload(IgniteCache<PersonKey, Person> cache) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>> Loading entries from database.");

        // Preload all person keys that are less than or equal to 3.
        cache.loadCache(null, PersonKey.class.getName(), "select * from PERSON where ID <= 3");



        for (Cache.Entry<PersonKey, Person> person : cache)
            System.out.println(">>> Loaded Person: " + person);
    }

    /**
     * Demonstrates cache read through from database.
     */
    private static void readThrough(IgniteCache<PersonKey, Person> cache) {
        PersonKey key = new PersonKey(4);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>> Read-through person from database for ID: " + key.getId());

        // Check that person with ID=4 is not in cache.
        Person p = cache.localPeek(key);

        assert p == null;

        // Read-through form database.
        p = cache.get(new PersonKey(4));

        System.out.println(">>> Loaded person from database: " + p);
    }

    /**
     * Demonstrates cache transaction joining database transaction.
     */
    private static void transaction(Ignite ignite, IgniteCache<PersonKey, Person> cache) {
        PersonKey key = new PersonKey(5);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>> Update salary and write-through to database for person with ID: " + key.getId());

        try (Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart()) {
            // Read-through from database.
            Person p = cache.get(key);

            System.out.println(">>> Loaded person from database: " + p);

            double salary = p.getSalary();

            // Raise salary by 20%.
            p.setSalary(salary * 1.2);

            // Write-through to database
            // and store in cache.
            cache.put(key, p);

            tx.commit();
        }

        System.out.println(">>> Updated person: " + cache.get(key));
    }
}
```

Here's my CacheConfig.java :

```
package apache.ignite.schemas; 

import java.sql.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import org.apache.ignite.cache.*; 
import org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.*; 
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.*; 

/** 
 * CacheConfig definition. 
 * 
 * Code generated by Apache Ignite Schema Import utility: 03/28/2016. 
 */ 
public class CacheConfig { 
    /** 
     * Create JDBC type for Person. 
     * 
     * @param cacheName Cache name. 
     * @return Configured JDBC type. 
     */ 
    private static JdbcType jdbcTypePerson(String cacheName) { 
        JdbcType jdbcType = new JdbcType(); 

    jdbcType.setCacheName(cacheName); 
    jdbcType.setDatabaseSchema("PERSON"); 
    jdbcType.setDatabaseTable("Person"); 
    jdbcType.setKeyType("org.apache.ignite.schema.PersonKey"); 
    jdbcType.setValueType("org.apache.ignite.schema.Person"); 

    // Key fields for Person. 
    Collection<JdbcTypeField> keys = new ArrayList<>(); 
    keys.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "id", int.class, "id")); 
    jdbcType.setKeyFields(keys.toArray(new JdbcTypeField[keys.size()])); 

    // Value fields for Person. 
    Collection<JdbcTypeField> vals = new ArrayList<>(); 
    vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "id", int.class, "id")); 
    vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "first_name", String.class, "firstName")); 
    vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "last_name", String.class, "lastName")); 
    vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.DOUBLE, "salary", double.class, "salary")); 
    jdbcType.setValueFields(vals.toArray(new JdbcTypeField[vals.size()])); 

    return jdbcType; 
} 

/** 
 * Create SQL Query descriptor for Person. 
 * 
 * @return Configured query entity. 
 */ 
private static QueryEntity queryEntityPerson() { 
    QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity(); 

    qryEntity.setKeyType("org.apache.ignite.schema.PersonKey"); 
    qryEntity.setValueType("org.apache.ignite.schema.Person"); 

    // Query fields for Person. 
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 

    fields.put("id", "int"); 
    fields.put("firstName", "String"); 
    fields.put("lastName", "String"); 
    fields.put("salary", "double"); 

    qryEntity.setFields(fields); 

    // Indexes for Person. 
    Collection<QueryIndex> idxs = new ArrayList<>(); 

    idxs.add(new QueryIndex("id", true, "PRIMARY")); 

    qryEntity.setIndexes(idxs); 

    return qryEntity; 
} 

/** 
 * Configure cache. 
 * 
 * @param cacheName Cache name. 
 * @param storeFactory Cache store factory. 
 * @return Cache configuration. 
 */ 
public static <K, V> CacheConfiguration<K, V> cache(String cacheName, CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<K, V> storeFactory) { 
    if (storeFactory == null) 
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cache store factory cannot be null."); 

    CacheConfiguration<K, V> ccfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheName); 

    ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(storeFactory); 
    ccfg.setReadThrough(true); 
    ccfg.setWriteThrough(true); 

    // Configure JDBC types. 
    Collection<JdbcType> jdbcTypes = new ArrayList<>(); 

    jdbcTypes.add(jdbcTypePerson(cacheName)); 

    storeFactory.setTypes(jdbcTypes.toArray(new JdbcType[jdbcTypes.size()])); 

    // Configure query entities. 
    Collection<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>(); 

    qryEntities.add(queryEntityPerson()); 

    ccfg.setQueryEntities(qryEntities); 

    return ccfg; 
}
```

}

Here's the Person.java :

```
package apache.ignite.schemas; 

import java.io.*; 

/** 
 * Person definition. 
 * 
 * Code generated by Apache Ignite Schema Import utility: 03/28/2016. 
 */ 
public class Person implements Serializable { 
    /** */ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L; 
/** Value for id. */ 
private int id; 

/** Value for firstName. */ 
private String firstName; 

/** Value for lastName. */ 
private String lastName; 

/** Value for salary. */ 
private double salary; 

/** 
 * Empty constructor. 
 */ 
public Person() { 
    // No-op. 
} 

/** 
 * Full constructor. 
 */ 
public Person( 
    int id, 
    String firstName, 
    String lastName, 
    double salary 
) { 
    this.id = id; 
    this.firstName = firstName; 
    this.lastName = lastName; 
    this.salary = salary; 
} 

/** 
 * Gets id. 
 * 
 * @return Value for id. 
 */ 
public int getId() { 
    return id; 
} 

/** 
 * Sets id. 
 * 
 * @param id New value for id. 
 */ 
public void setId(int id) { 
    this.id = id; 
} 

/** 
 * Gets firstName. 
 * 
 * @return Value for firstName. 
 */ 
public String getFirstName() { 
    return firstName; 
} 

/** 
 * Sets firstName. 
 * 
 * @param firstName New value for firstName. 
 */ 
public void setFirstName(String firstName) { 
    this.firstName = firstName; 
} 

/** 
 * Gets lastName. 
 * 
 * @return Value for lastName. 
 */ 
public String getLastName() { 
    return lastName; 
} 

/** 
 * Sets lastName. 
 * 
 * @param lastName New value for lastName. 
 */ 
public void setLastName(String lastName) { 
    this.lastName = lastName; 
} 

/** 
 * Gets salary. 
 * 
 * @return Value for salary. 
 */ 
public double getSalary() { 
    return salary; 
} 

/** 
 * Sets salary. 
 * 
 * @param salary New value for salary. 
 */ 
public void setSalary(double salary) { 
    this.salary = salary; 
} 

/** {@inheritDoc} */ 
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) { 
    if (this == o) 
        return true; 

    if (!(o instanceof Person)) 
        return false; 

    Person that = (Person)o; 

    if (id != that.id) 
        return false; 

    if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) 
        return false; 

    if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null) 
        return false; 

    if (Double.compare(salary, that.salary) != 0) 
        return false; 

    return true; 
} 

/** {@inheritDoc} */ 
@Override public int hashCode() { 
    int res = id; 

    res = 31 * res + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0); 

    res = 31 * res + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0); 

    long ig_hash_temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(salary); 

    res = 31 * res + (int)(ig_hash_temp ^ (ig_hash_temp >>> 32)); 

    return res; 
} 

/** {@inheritDoc} */ 
@Override public String toString() { 
    return "Person [id=" + id + 
        ", firstName=" + firstName + 
        ", lastName=" + lastName + 
        ", salary=" + salary + 
        "]"; 
}
```

}

Here's the PersonKey.java :

```
package apache.ignite.schemas; 

import java.io.*; 

/** 
 * PersonKey definition. 
 * 
 * Code generated by Apache Ignite Schema Import utility: 03/28/2016. 
 */ 
public class PersonKey implements Serializable { 
    /** */ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L; 

/** Value for id. */ 
private int id; 

/** 
 * Empty constructor. 
 */ 
public PersonKey() { 
    // No-op. 
} 

/** 
 * Full constructor. 
 */ 
public PersonKey( 
    int id 
) { 
    this.id = id; 
} 

/** 
 * Gets id. 
 * 
 * @return Value for id. 
 */ 
public int getId() { 
    return id; 
} 

/** 
 * Sets id. 
 * 
 * @param id New value for id. 
 */ 
public void setId(int id) { 
    this.id = id; 
} 

/** {@inheritDoc} */ 
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) { 
    if (this == o) 
        return true; 

    if (!(o instanceof PersonKey)) 
        return false; 

    PersonKey that = (PersonKey)o; 

    if (id != that.id) 
        return false; 

    return true; 
} 

/** {@inheritDoc} */ 
@Override public int hashCode() { 
    int res = id; 

    return res; 
} 

/** {@inheritDoc} */ 
@Override public String toString() { 
    return "PersonKey [id=" + id + 
        "]"; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like type metadata for cache is not configured.

Please check CacheConfiguration class. It should contains the next method:

```
/**
 * Create JDBC type for Person.
 *
 * @param cacheName Cache name.
 * @return Configured JDBC type.
 */
private static JdbcType jdbcTypePerson(String cacheName) {
    JdbcType jdbcType = new JdbcType();
    jdbcType.setCacheName(cacheName);
    jdbcType.setDatabaseSchema("PUBLIC");
    jdbcType.setDatabaseTable("PERSON");
    jdbcType.setKeyType("org.apache.ignite.PersonKey");
    jdbcType.setValueType("org.apache.ignite.Person");
    jdbcType.setKeyFields(
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.NUMERIC, "ID", long.class, "id")
    );
    jdbcType.setValueFields(
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "FIRST_NAME", String.class, "firstName"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "LAST_NAME", String.class, "lastName"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.DOUBLE, "SALARY", Double.class, "salary")
    );
    return jdbcType;
}
```

that used in "cache" method in the following way:

```
// Configure JDBC types.
Collection<JdbcType> jdbcTypes = new ArrayList<>();
jdbcTypes.add(jdbcTypePerson(cacheName));
storeFactory.setTypes(jdbcTypes.toArray(new JdbcType[jdbcTypes.size()]));
```

That configuration work perfectly for me with H2 database.

If my answer does not help to you please provide full source code of your example.

**Edit:**

You have incorrectly configured key type and value type in JdbcType and QueryEntity configurations.

The described configurations and POJO classes have different package.

Change the next descriptions:

```
jdbcType.setKeyType("org.apache.ignite.schema.PersonKey"); 
jdbcType.setValueType("org.apache.ignite.schema.Person");
```

to

```
jdbcType.setKeyType("apache.ignite.schemas.PersonKey"); 
jdbcType.setValueType("apache.ignite.schemas.Person");
```

and

```
qryEntity.setKeyType("org.apache.ignite.schema.PersonKey"); 
qryEntity.setValueType("org.apache.ignite.schema.Person");
```

to

```
qryEntity.setKeyType("apache.ignite.schemas.PersonKey"); 
qryEntity.setValueType("apache.ignite.schemas.Person");
```

Comment: I have updated my question to add all the source code files. Please help me fix it with mysql. Thanks.